# How does one get the MinionPro \qoppa?

Tags: greek, minionpro

Since I have switched to the 2014 texlive, one issue is not working: the character `\qoppa`. The command is defined in polutonikogreek in babel. It is an archaic greek letter, but was used also in classic times for the number 90.

The glyph is available in the cmr font and in MinionPro and in the beautiful MinionMath font of Johannes Küster. I want the latter. In MinionPro/MinionMath, it is unicode character 03d9 (formerly u+03DE, it recently changed, as it turns out), see http://www.typoma.de/data/MinionMath_Release_1_021.pdf

How do I get the glyph into latex? I tried

```
\def\testqoppa{\begingroup\fontfamily{MinionPro}\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\char19\endgroup}
```

and

```
\def\testqoppab{\begingroup\fontfamily{minionmath}\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\char19\endgroup}
```

But all this gives the cmr glyph, because latex complains

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/MinionPro/m/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/minionmath/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 571.
```

This seems like a beginner error from my side. Can somebody help me to get it right? I need `\qoppa` only in two places, so a nasty trick is also sufficient. The MinionMath font is installed and is working for all other purposes. Here is an extract of the `.cls` file:

```
\usepackage[fullfamily,textlf, opticals, swash, onlytext]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[extraops,textcomp,withamsmath,amssymb]{minionmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{minionamsmath}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,greek,latin,french,italian,german,british]{babel}
```

Comment: Did you try with `\fontfamily{MinionPro-LF}`?

Comment: In \testqoppa, it does not work. Is there another way?

Comment: It still gives the cmr glyph.

Comment: @MotionMountain I think we could do with a MWE showing how you are loading the font. (I'm guessing you are using pdfLaTeX and `\usepackage{MinionPro}`, but could be wrong!) Also, the Minion Math package doesn't seem to have an `LGR` encoding at all (probably not surprising).

Comment: To be clear, looking at the `MinionPro` LaTeX support, the encoding files are called for example `LGRMinionPro-LF.fd` so if they are installed `kpsewhich LGRMinionPro-LF.fd` should find them and @karlkoeller's suggestion should work.

Comment: kpsewhich LGRMinionPro-LF.fd gives, in texlive:
./LGRMinionPro-LF.fd which means that it is indeed installed. Yet it does not work...

Comment: @MotionMountain See the answer.

Comment: @JosephWright It was a problem of code number. In Minion Pro it has code 18...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiling the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
\xfonttable{LGR}{MinionPro-LF}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

you can see that the character you're looking for has code `18`:

[image]

So, the right definition for `\testqoppa` is

```
\def\testqoppa{\begingroup\fontfamily{MinionPro-LF}\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\char18\endgroup}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\def\testqoppa{\begingroup\fontfamily{MinionPro-LF}\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\char18\endgroup}

\begin{document}

This is the symbol I was looking for\ldots \testqoppa

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` would be safer; also `\char18` should be `\symbol{18}` (the same, but the latter is documented, the former isn't in the LaTeX manual).

Comment: The confusion stems from a bug in the older versions of MinionPro from Adobe. The "q-like" qoppa should be in u+03D9, but used to be on position u+03DE. It was wrong in all font versions including 2.068. Adobe switched to the correct position in version 2.103.

Comment: In fact, the q-like qoppa should be in position 19, whereas the zig-zag like qoppa should be in position 18 in LGR encoding. So there is also a related LGR coding issue with MinionPro.

Comment: And we are not yet talking about stigma, the other archaic character, where the Adobe MinionPro Font still has characters/glyphs on the wrong unicode positions...